# Double scroll bar

Tags: google-chrome

I have a double scroll bar in Chrome viewing this website.

http://msvixen.tv/forums/

I have tried adding the "overflow: hidden;" but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `overflow-y: scroll !important;` set for your `html` element, right under `XenForo Core CSS`. That's probably not what you want. Getting rid of that line fixes the double scroll bar.